# Stuck at File Upload Download App in DropBox using java

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on `Dropbox api` using java.
first app is to upload and download file in dropbox account.
I got a token to authenticate with dropbox but when i try to uploading file in account i get bad request error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadResponse: unexpected response code: 401
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$4.handle(DbxClient.java:274)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$4.handle(DbxClient.java:270)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.doGet(DbxRequestUtil.java:265)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.doGet(DbxClient.java:1912)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.getAccountInfo(DbxClient.java:270)
    at com.prit.net.Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

My code is below `package com.prit.net`;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxClient;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxException;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthNoRedirect;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxWriteMode;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException, URISyntaxException {
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "mykey"; // change with yours
    final String APP_SECRET = "mysecret"; // change with yours

    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    //Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(authorizeUrl).toURI());
    // System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    // System.out
    // .println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
    // System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
    // String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    // .readLine().trim();
    //DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
    // System.out.println("Access token is:");
    // System.out.println(authFinish.accessToken.toString());

    // save the value of myToken to a file for future use
    String myToken = "myTokensecretkeyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // change with
                                                                // yours
    // DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, authFinish.accessToken);
    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, myToken);
    System.out.println(config);
    System.out.println(myToken);

    System.out.println("check1");
    File inputFile = new File("C:\\Dev\\foo.txt");
    System.out.println("check2");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    System.out.println("check3");
    try {
        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/FileApiDemo/fooup2.txt",
                DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
        System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/FileApiDemo");
    System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
    for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
        System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
    }

    // download file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Dev\\downloadedfile.txt");
        try {
            DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/FileApiDemo/fooup2.txt", null,  outputStream);
            System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
        }     finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }

    }

} `
```

Comment: 401 is typically "Unauthorized". You should check your credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the value of `myToken`. The commented code you have above that presumably gets you a working access token, right? If so, make sure the access token you see at the end of that flow is the one you're saving and using on subsequent runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic upload example to Dropbox. The example is working with DropBox API v2.

the client variable in the example is from using the `DbxClientV2....`

```
try
        {
            File file = new File("C:\\... Storage location of file on local system");
            //reads file as input for the method to dropbox
            InputStream fileupload = new FileInputStream(file);
            //path in dropbox account to store the file 
            // if want to store it in root just put '/'
            //if want to store file in a folder '/foldername/'
            client.files().uploadBuilder("/" + file.getName())
                    .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE)//always overwrites the existing file in the dropbox folder
                    .uploadAndFinish(fileupload);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File uploaded to dropbox");
        }
        //exception handled
        catch (DbxException e)
        {
            //error message for uploading file to dropboxcloud
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to upload file to Cloud \n Error: " + e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to upload file to cloud \n Error: " + e);
        }
```

This basic example does not include the progress of file upload to cloud or any other checks.

Hope this is helpful