# code has expired (within the last hour) dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Hi everyone i am new in dropbox api (php version).

i am getting authCode using authorizeUrl, its working good for only one time if i reload page error message shows on

`'HTTP status 400 {"error_description": "code has expired (within the last hour)", "error": "invalid_grant"}`
how to get permanent authCode from dropbox.

```
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("api-key.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
$authCode = "****************************************";

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);
```

Comment: Same error, other language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853375/dropbox-core-api-java-authorization-code

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this error

some steps to solve this problem

1. go to Apps page [Dropbox apps](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps)
2. add your site or localhost link to ***OAuth 2* Redirect URIs**
3. next to generate access token, then copy the access token and use it .
4. finally remove this lines

> list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
>   print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

and paste directly in your access token into

> $accessToken =
>   "VTEp2cvkQ8************************************";

it's working perfectly